# ST_Union on Rasters in Geoalchemy2 using ORM

Tags: postgis, python-3, geoalchemy-2

I am attempting to perform a union on two rasters I pick from my postgis database using GeoAlchemy2.

I have a Raster table defined:

```
from geoalchemy2 import Raster
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

Base = declarative_base()

class RasterData(Base):
'''
Raster class
'''
__tablename__ = 'images'
__table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
raster = Column(Raster)
```

Then I attempt to use ORM to union two raster tiles using

```
engine = create_engine(db_str, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session(expire_on_commit=False)

rasters = session.query(RasterData.raster).limit(2).all()
merged = session.query(func.ST_Union(rasters)).all()
```

This unfortunately errors out with:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'RasterElement'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

It seems I might need to cast this as something else but I am unsure what. Any ideas what the code above is missing to complete the union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to pass the `type_` kwarg to the function `ST_Union`.

E.g.

```
merged = session.query(func.ST_Union(RasterData.raster, type_=Raster)).all()
```

Thanks to the developers of Geoalchemy2 who pointed this out.

Example shown in their gallery:
[Reproject A Raster using ST_Transform](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/test_raster_transform.html#reproject-a-raster-using-st-transform) usage on Line 54